# react-native - itemTextStyle and itemStyle not working in Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Hi guys I have a problem there. I want to style my picker item fontSize, I use itemTextStyle prop, but it seems only working on iOS. How to make it also works in Android? Here's my code. Thanks!

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 160, marginTop: -12 }}
  itemTextStyle={{ fontSize: 5 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ language: itemValue })}>
  <Picker.Item color='grey' label="A" value="a" />
  <Picker.Item label="B" value="b" />
  <Picker.Item label="C" value="c" />
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the picker in Android you can do so by overriding the default styling inside

> android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Add the new styles inside the AppTheme

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SpinnerItem">
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SpinnerDropDownItem">
        <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```